# AS3 MouseEvent.CLICK on img not working

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent

Iam begginer in AS, I made banner with XML content (import articles - titles and images) and I also need to make click web connection with this content. This is final banner: http://tenisovysvet.sk/TS_banner.swf

Titles are working (htmlText) but images nope (just MouseEvent.CLICK)...

Thanks for any advice!

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var imageLoader:Loader;
var imageRequest:URLRequest;

imageLoader = new Loader();
imageRequest = new URLRequest(xmlData.clanok[0].foto);
imageLoader.load(imageRequest);

imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,showPic);

function showPic(e:Event):void
{

    imageLoader.content.width = 140;
    imageLoader.content.height = 87;
    imageLoader.content.x = 10;
    imageLoader.content.y = 65;

    imageLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked1);
    function buttonClicked1(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var buttonClicked1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.google.co.uk");
        navigateToURL(buttonClicked1, "_blank");
    }

    addChild(imageLoader.content);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to place your function "buttonClicked1" outside of the function "showPic".
Create a Sprite and add the imageLoader.content to the Sprite, add the sprite to the stage and also assign the MouseEvent Listener to the Sprite instead of the image:

```
function showPic(e: Event): void {

    var imageHolder: Sprite = new Sprite();
    imageHolder.addChild(imageLoader.content);

    imageHolder.buttonMode = true;
    imageHolder.width = 140;
    imageHolder.height = 87;
    imageHolder.x = 10;
    imageHolder.y = 65;

    imageHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked1);

    addChild(imageHolder);

}

function buttonClicked1(event: MouseEvent): void {
    var buttonClicked1: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.google.co.uk");
    navigateToURL(buttonClicked1, "_blank");
}
```

Comment: still not working ... this is final banner - http://tenisovysvet.sk/TS_banner.swf

Comment: Change the line "imageLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked1);" to "imageLoader.content.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked1);". Your imageLoader is actually not being placed on stage hence it cannot receive MouseEvents.